# Как покрасить террейн в unity?

Tags: unity3d

Как покрасить террейн в unity?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Terrain Layer -> Create layer. Нигде не было написано что нужно создать новый лейер. [НИГДЕ](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TerrainLayer.html).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]